# Shuffling one column of pandas df with sample

Tags: python, pandas

When I do the following I seem to wind up with the original df,

```
train['col1'] = train['col1'].sample(frac=1)
```

While if I use .values I get the shuffle I was after:

```
train['col1'] = train['col1'].sample(frac=1).values
```

I'm unclear why this happens - any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the version without `.values` keeps the `index` and the column preserves its order.